# Rotating instances in geometry nodes causes it to stretch

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been stuck on this for hours. Internet hasn't helped me and I seem to be a unique case and need to finish this today.

Trying to create a Minecraft scene with arrows scattered all over the place from a battle. However, when trying to rotate the arrow instances, it stretches as I rotate it. I thought it was because I hadn't applied the transforms to the original arrow so I did that to no avail.

Here is the result.
[image]

I have seen that it is connected to the origin of the plane I am using for the geometry nodes as when changing the origin point, the stretching goes into different directions.

Here are my geometry nodes
[image]

I am using the MCPrep Blender addon to add in the arrows.

Please, can someone help me with this? I need help with this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trying to fix it and just asking the question myself, I managed to fix it and that was to ensure I applied the transformation on the plane, not the arrow. I completely forgot the plane exists.

If anyone comes across the same problem as me, always make sure you apply transformations. Also, ensure you do it with the geometry nodes off as it will make your Blender software stop responding.